# Чтение из файла в bash-е

Tags: файлы, bash

Как прочитать значение числа записанного в файле на последней строке и присвоить его переменной в bash-e?

Answer (score 3):

```
>cat 1.txt
1
2
3
4
5
>tail -n 1 1.txt
5
```

в баше будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
a=`tail -n 1 1.txt`
```